# How to find $\nabla_{vec(A)} |A|$ where $|A|$ is the determinant of $A$ and $vec(\cdot)$ is the vectorization operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix.  Let the determinant of $A$ be given by $|A|$.

How to find the following gradient
\begin{align}
\nabla_{vec(A)} |A|
\end{align}
that is how to find gradient of $|A|$ with respec to $vec(A)$ where $vec(\cdot)$ is the vectorization operator.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\def\v{{\rm vec}}$Use
the well-known [Jacobi formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) to calculate the differential with respect to the matrix itself
$$\eqalign{
d\det(A) &= \det(A)\,A^{-T}:dA \\
 &= \det(A)\,A^{-1}:dA \qquad \big(A\,\,{\rm is\,\,symmetric}\big) \\
}$$
[Vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) this expression to calculate the differential with respect to the vector, then construct the desired gradient.
$$\eqalign{
d\det(A) &= \det(A)\,\v(A^{-1}):\v(dA) \\
\p{\det(A)}{\v(A)} &= \det(A)\,\v(A^{-1}) \\\\
}$$

---

In the above, a colon is used as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \\
}$$